# What would happen if a gas mixture is cooled to a temperature between the individual boiling points of the constituent gases?

Tags: thermodynamics

Say there is a bucket filled with liquid nitrogen (-196$^\circ$C), and a pipe running through the bucket. In one end of the pipe, a gas mixture is pumped at a very low flow rate, and vented at the other end of the pipe to atmosphere. The gas mixture used is, say, 5% Methane (boiling point -161$^\circ$C) & 95% Neon (boiling point -246$^\circ$C). Initially, the gas mixture is at room temperature (20$^\circ$C) before it enters the pipe. Assume the length of submerged pipe is long enough, and the flow rate is low enough, that the gas mixture cools at least below the boiling point of methane, but (obviously) not below that of neon.

What happens to the gas mixture in the pipe, specifically related to the relative concentrations of the species' and possible phase changes of the constituents?

I can think of two possible scenarios, but I'm not sure which is correct, if any:

1. The methane condenses and the neon stays gaseous, and the vented gas from the pipe has a higher neon concentration than went in, or
2. Nothing happens to the relative concentrations of each species as the boiling point of the *mixture* (about -240$^\circ$C) is still below that of liquid nitrogen.

Follow-up: If the answer is 2, is there any alternate scenario where 1 could happen? (e.g. different temperature heat bath, different gas pressures, different concentrations, etc.)

Comment: As an approximation, what does Raoult's law tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the principle of *distillation*: if you cool steam, the water condenses out, and the other components of air (oxygen, nitrogen etc) stay in the gaseous phase. The result of cooling moist air is that it becomes "dryer".

The exact same principle applies in the situation you describe - the gas that is cooled below its boiling point will condense, and the output will be enriched in the component that remained above its boiling point.

So your scenario 1 is what will happen in practice.

You might want to read [this description of the liquefaction of oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryogenic_oxygen_plant) - you see a lot of the elements of what you describe in your question.